# What is the coding standard and design pattern followed by mango blog based on CF

Tags: design-patterns, coding-style, coldfusion, standards

We are looking forward to migrating our ColdFusion project into a new MVC architecture and are evaluating many frameworks and design patterns.

I found that the coding standard and design patterns followed by my ColdFusion-based Mango blog is awesome, but I couldn't find any documentation regarding the same on the Internet.

Does anyone know what coding standard and design patterns they are following?

Is there any documentation for the same available?

Is there any similar coding standard available?

[Link to Mango Blog](http://www.mangoblog.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better either asking on their [forums](http://www.mangoblog.org/forums/forums.cfm?conferenceid=9AE6B18E-3048-2A53-70ED34C1EDD7251D) or [contacting the authors](http://www.asfusion.com/contact/) directly.